# How to close a hole in a model?

Tags: modeling

I've watched several tutorials but I'm still struggling with what should be a simple task. I would like to modify a mesh imported from STL file for 3D printing it. The model has a solid surface with a pass-trough hole that I'd like to close. I selected the upper border of the hole and closed it by pressing <kbd>F</kbd>, then I did the same on the lower border. This effectively closes the hole but it leaves the inner walls of the hole. Hope the picture explains better.

This is what I obtained (section):

[image]

I'd like to get to this:

[image]

What is the right procedure?

Comment: As it stands it's difficult to understand exactly what you're asking. Post an image of your object in Edit mode showing the problem. You can use Blender's Window > Save Screenshot to do that, then edit your question and add the image. You can also share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page to add the link to your question.

Comment: Hi, @DeadMeat. Since you hinted you might not be particularly happy with your English, I attempted to improve it a bit by editing in hopes this would make the question a bit easier to understand. I hope you don't mind my edit. Please, edit it again if you feel I changed what you meant to say.

Comment: Hi @MartynasŽiemys you perfectly summarized , thank you very much. That is exactly what I am trying to achieve. The only difference is that the "hole" has an irregular shape (i.e. not circular) but I'd assume the procedure is the same...

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>F</kbd> hotkey is for Make Edge/Face operation and it does just that - only fills whatever is selected with a face, but it does not remove any geometry so if the hole has walls, you still have to remove them after making the faces that cover it. You need to select the faces that make up the walls of the hole and delete them with <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, got it. what was confusing me is that if I first close the hole it becomes quite difficult to properly select the internal faces.  Deleting the faces before like @laserlars suggested made things a lot easier and I managed. I now need to understand how to properly select the internal faces in case of irregular shapes, but in any case manually selecting solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

to do this you have to switch to edit mode and right next to it, select face select at select mode. Now you can only select the inner walls of the through hole and press del.
in the appearing delete popup choose faces.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You should first delete the inner 'tube' and then fill the holes, since selections are easier this way.

Go into Edit Mode and select a face inside the hole, then *Select > Select Linked > Linked Flat Faces* and increase the 'Sharpness' threshold until all inner faces are selected.

[image: select face]

[image: select linked]

Then delete the orange 'tube'
[image: delete faces]

**Alt+Leftclick** one edge segment to get the whole ring and hit F to fill the Face.
[image: select ring]
[image: fill]

Repeat the last 2 steps for the bottom side.

Comment: Thank you @laserlars, this actually did the trick. Only problem the selection of flat faces didn't work. I assume it depends on the shape of the "hole" that is not regular but selecting individual faces one by one and deleting did exactly what I needed. I now need to practice with the select tools.